# C read from Console limit char input.How to do it?

Tags: c, console

I am trying to build my first Windows TUI Console app  and i am facing some problems...
Scanf nor fgets prevents user from entering unlimted characters unless hits enter etc..
In a TUI interface thats a problem.. because it can get overwrite the line below...
Is there any solution for this apart from getch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there isn't, at least not portably. C input is stream based, and doesn't have a concept of a keyboard. If you really want to write a text user interface, use [ncurses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) or [pdcurses](http://pdcurses.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: That would be pdcurses for Win32.

Comment: @ninjalj According to its website that would be pdcurses for " DOS, 
OS/2, Win32, X11 and SDL"

Comment: there is way to switch it to non stream mode